# How to set the key animation down from 250

Tags: animation

I see in the animation bar it goes up to 250. how can I put these down?

Answer (score 2):

Change the number in the "End" box under the timeline.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the animation bar (called Timeline btw) put your click on frame you want to end and press E to set the endframe of the animation. Same thing for the start frame but with S.

Answer (score 1):

Also can change in render tab.

[image]